# Графы количество компонентов связности

Tags: графы

Не понимаю, почему неправильно
Вопрос звучит так:

**Для любого графа, в худшем случае количество компонент связности:**

1. logv
2. V
3. V log V
4. V^2

**Я ответил V ведь худший случай это же O(v+E+......n)?**

Comment: Что такое здесь "в худшем случае"?????? Наибольшее количество - да, V

Comment: Я тоже так ответил, что V оказалось неправильно(

Comment: К чему относится худший случай? К какому алгоритму?

Comment: Вот и пытаюсь тут понять(